# What are typical drupal 7 absolute resource URLs?

Tags: settings, resource-urls

As the question says - what are the typical drupal absolute resource urls?

Is it:

- CiviCRM Resource URL  https://example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/
- Image Upload URL https://example.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/
- Extension Resource URL https://example.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext

or is it:

- CiviCRM Resource URL  https://example.org
- Image Upload URL https://example.org/civicrm/persist/contribute/
- Extension Resource URL https://example.org/civicrm/ext

or is it something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install a drupal 7 tarball and mostly keep clicking next, and then install a civi tarball and mostly click next, it's the first set you've listed.

It is definitely not the 2nd one.

But to be fully absolute you need to include http:// or https://